# Conditional array formatting in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with text strings:

```
var myarray = ["valueA","valueB","valueC","valueD/valueA","valueE","valueC/valueA"];
```

Some of the values in the array have a slash, *e.g.* "aaa/bbb". The slash have a special meaning of separating two values.

I want to get a new array with one value or the other based on a boolean function.

For example:

```
var myarray = ["valueA/valueB"];
var myNewarray = myFunction(myarray, true); // myNewarray == ["valueA"]
var myNewarray2 = myFunction(myarray, false); // myNewarray2 == ["valueB"]

myarray = ["valueA/valueC","valueB","valueD/valueF"];
myNewarray = myFunction(myarray, true); // ["valueA","valueB","valueD"]
myNewarray = myFunction(myarray, false); // ["valueC","valueB","valueF"]
```

Comment: Does the fiddle link have anything to do with your question?!

Comment: Yes i want chose value with time if i have even week i chose value 1 if odd i chose value 2 (
myarray = [value1/value2])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.map` to call a function on each item and return another value depending on some conditions.

```
var cond = false;
var myarray = ["valueA/valueC","valueB","valueD/valueF"];
var myNewarray = myarray.map( function(item){
    var values = item.split('/');
    if( values.length == 2 ){
        return cond ? values[0] : values[1];
    }
    else {
        return item;
    }
});
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/duw99072/

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through your array and `.split()` on the slash if the element contains it:

Assuming you want the value of `oddWeek` (in your fiddle) to determine the left/right value of the slash-separated array elements:

```js
var myarray = ["valueA/valueC","valueB","valueD/valueF"];
myarray.forEach(function (val, index, array) {
    if (val.indexOf('/') > -1) {
        val = val.split('/')[oddWeek];
    }
    output += '<p>' + val + '</p>'
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/r1hvbjs5/2/

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Array.prototype.map` - it creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

Considering your variable is named `condition`:

```
myarray.map(function(el){
 return el.indexOf('/') > -1 ? el.split('/')[condition ? 0 : 1] : el;
});
```